# SQL Like operator return null

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i use **Like** operator on a column which string type, return zero result even there is a data that matches the criteria.

even interesting it is only 'ga' return zero shown in example below.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempPersons
(
    FirstName varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Anne Daugaard')
INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Jenne Neergaard')
INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Mark Daugaard')
INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Hans Daugaard')
INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Alle Daugaard')
INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Kent Daugaard')
INSERT INTO #TempPersons (FirstName) VALUES ('Mavi Gilbeert')

SELECT * FROM #TempPersons  WHERE FirstName LIKE '%ga%'

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempPersons', N'U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE #TempPersons;
```

No result when firstname like 'ga', but when firstname like 'gaa' or like 'daugaa' there are hits.

is 'ga' something special?

Comment: I guessed that the database is SQL Server.  Please tag your questions with the database you are actually using.

Comment: for me your like clause look correct, may be you missing some thing

Comment: Your case actually works perfectly fine for me. Doublecheck your statements. Maybe some special characters at play?

Comment: I checked you query. It worked for 'gaa' as well as 'ga'.

Comment: It is working fine with 'ga'. Please check your problem by executing your queries step by step then you can find the problem.

Comment: I have found out that SQL manager i am using to execute this script on a SQL server which has a different version than manager. I have executed on server itself and got the correct result. But still its unclear why this happens.